# prompt for password ONLY for push (but not pull)

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I'd like to make my command line git client prompt for a password (as a reminder that I should think twice before pushing changes to a repo which are irreversible without admin access such as temporary branches or unsquashed/badly described commits), but I don't want to have to authenticate myself each time I want to pull (and my code base changes regularly).

At the moment I have to type in my username and password twice, once for `git pull` and once for `git push`. Can I restrict the prompting to just push?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I restrict the prompting to just push?

Yes: you can set your default url with your username in it, as I mention in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33425297/6309).

```
git remote set-url https://<yourUsername>@github.com/<yourUsername>/<yourRepo>
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you also can define a push url *without* your username

```
git config remote.origin.pushURL url https://github.com/<yourUsername>/<yourRepo>
```

When pushing, you would have to enter your username, while pulling would only ask for the password.
If you have a **[credential helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)**, that means:

- pull will ask for the password only once per session (and keep the password in memory)
- push would ask for your username (and then the credential helper would take over)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could set separate URLs for pushing and tracking.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat didn't you accept this answer before?

Comment: Hmmmm, so this doesn't actually make the pull touchless unless you use credential helper does it?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to use the credential helper.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat are you on Windows? If yes, type `git config credential.helper wincred` in your repo, and give it a try: it will ask you for password only once.

Comment: I'm not using Windows. I'm on Mac.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat then you can follow https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-mac

Comment: Great, that completes what I needed. I've marked the answer as correct again.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The osx credentials helper makes the push touchless now.