# Prompt for password but not username?

Tags: git, git-push

Is it possible to get git to prompt only for a password, and determine your username automatically? I want to have the extra layer of manual intervention as a reminder to be careful what I push, but just entering a password and not also the username every time is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using https url, you can change said url in order to include your username just before the git repos hosting server (here, for instance, `github.com`):

```
git remote set-url origin https://<yourUsername>@github.com/<yourUsername>/<yourRepo>
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Each time you will `git push`, it will ask only for your password.

Comment: I guess this will work, though I'm not sure of the exact steps to modify my repo to set this up. My `git remote -v` command outputs a fetch and a push URL for the `origin` branch so I'm not sure how to apply this command to one of them and whether a branch name needs to be specified.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat sorry, I forgot origin in the command. I have edited the answer, and you can use said command to change the remote origin URL.